# Permission denied error 13 - Python on Hadoop

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop-streaming

I am running a simple Python mapper and reducer and am getting `13 permission denied error`. Need help.

I am not sure what is happening here and need help. New to Hadoop world.

I am running simple map reduce for counting word. The mapper and reducer are running independently on linus or windows powershell

```
======================================================================


hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar -file /home/hadoop/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file /home/hadoop/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /deepw/pg4300.txt -output /deepw/pg3055
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

packageJobJar: [/home/hadoop/mapper.py, /home/hadoop/reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/hadoop-unjar2961168567699201508/] [] /tmp/streamjob4125164474101219622.jar tmpDir=null
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
15/09/23 14:39:16 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local]
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201509231312_0003
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /home/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../bin/hadoop job -Dmapred.job.tracker=192.168.56.102:9001 -kill job_201509231312_0003
15/09/23 14:39:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://192.168.56.102:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201509231312_0003
15/09/23 14:39:17 INFO streaming.StreamJob: map 0% reduce 0%
15/09/23 14:39:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: map 100% reduce 100%
15/09/23 14:39:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
15/09/23 14:39:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /home/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../bin/hadoop job -Dmapred.job.tracker=192.168.56.102:9001 -kill job_201509231312_0003
15/09/23 14:39:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://192.168.56.102:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201509231312_0003
15/09/23 14:39:41 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201509231312_0003_m_000000
15/09/23 14:39:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!

================================================================
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509231312_0003/attempt_201509231312_0003_m_000001_3/work/./mapper.py": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 24 more
```

Comment: try to add `sudo` before your command

Comment: Adding sudo did not worked either.java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/root/jobcache/job_201509231626_0007/attempt_201509231626_0007_m_000000_3/work/./mapper.py": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Are the permissions down the entire path "/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509231312_0003/attempt_201509231312_0003_m_000001_3/work/./mapper.py" looking correct for you to be able to execute that program and make sure that none of your file systems are full.

Comment: how to provide permission for entire path any pointers would be helpful

Comment: @SwadeepMishra My question was Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: Have you read this link, which seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276231/hadoop-on-centos-streaming-example-with-python-permission-denied-on-mapred-lo?rq=1

Comment: I read that and it does not have an answer. How to run daemons as user hadoop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your mapper file is not executable. Try `chmod a+x mapper.py` before submitting your job.

Alternatively, in your command, you can replace

```
-mapper mapper.py
```

with

```
-mapper "python mapper.py"
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! CAPS INTENDED FOR A BIG THANK YOU!! It worked after adding python keyword infront of mapper..but not working with chmod a+x, not sure why...here is how my mapper looks like after executing chmod: 4 -rwxrwxr-x 1 hadoop hadoop 534 Sep 28 10:47 /home/hadoop/mapper.py, seems like something going wrong when copying to some temp directory.  Can you please help me with that?

Comment: to provide access I executed " chmod a+x /home/hadoop/mapper.py' and same for reducer.

Comment: Are you including `-reducer "python reduce.py"` in your command, and are you including `-file mapper.py -file reduce.py` in your command?

Comment: yes sir, I was doing something like "hadoop jar jar-file-path -file mapper-path -mapper 'python mapper-path' -file reducer-path -reducer 'python reducer-path' -input /hdfs-input path -output /hdfs-output path

Comment: While you have to give complete mapper and reducer paths in the `-file` option, in `-mapper` and `-reducer` options, you have to provide only file-names. So it would be just `-reducer "python reduce.py` and `python mapper.py`

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why it does not work without specifying python? I read at michael Nolls write up that it should work and he also demonstrated it.

Comment: Did you add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at top of your scripts?

Comment: I did add #!usr/bin/env but not python so will add and see if it works. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: kampta you are the MAN (or may be a WOMAN). THANKS BUDDY. It worked with adding python in python files.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, I recently also had this error13 problem. However, in my case, the problem was that the directory the python executable and the mappers/reducers were in had a permissions problem; it was not readable by others. After a chmod a+rx , my problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After doing `chmod a+x` for mapper and reduce `.py` files I am getting below exceptions (with python keyword added to mapper it works fine and produces right results).

```
========================================================================================

5-09-28 13:25:16,572 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2015-09-28 13:25:16,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/META-INF <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/META-INF
2015-09-28 13:25:16,761 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/reducer.py <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/reducer.py
2015-09-28 13:25:16,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/job.jar <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/job.jar
2015-09-28 13:25:16,766 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/.job.jar.crc <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/.job.jar.crc
2015-09-28 13:25:16,769 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/org <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/org
2015-09-28 13:25:16,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/jars/mapper.py <- /deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/mapper.py
2015-09-28 13:25:17,046 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2015-09-28 13:25:17,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2015-09-28 13:25:17,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1e7c7fb
2015-09-28 13:25:17,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://192.168.56.101:9000/swad/4300.txt:0+786539
2015-09-28 13:25:17,275 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
2015-09-28 13:25:17,287 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2015-09-28 13:25:17,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
2015-09-28 13:25:17,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
2015-09-28 13:25:17,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
2015-09-28 13:25:17,419 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/./mapper.py]
2015-09-28 13:25:17,436 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: configuration exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more
2015-09-28 13:25:17,462 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2015-09-28 13:25:17,495 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Initialized cache for UID to User mapping with a cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
2015-09-28 13:25:17,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Got UserName hadoop for UID 1000 from the native implementation
2015-09-28 13:25:17,498 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/deep/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201509281234_0015/attempt_201509281234_0015_m_000000_3/work/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more
2015-09-28 13:25:17,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this as well. I found that when I was running on a single node, the Cloudera QuickStart VM, it all worked but on a cluster it didn't. It seems the python scripts are not being shipped to the nodes for execution.

There is another parameter "-file" which ships a file or directory as part of the job. It is mentioned here:

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming

You can specify this file multiple times, once for the mapper and again for the reducer, like this:

hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/linux/input -output /user/linux/output_new -mapper wordcount_mapper.py -reducer wordcount_reducer.py  -file /home/linux/wordcount_mapper.py -file /home/linux/wordcount_reducer.py

or you can package the scripts in a directory and ship just the directory, like this:

hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/linux/input -output /user/linux/output_new -mapper wc/wordcount_mapper.py -reducer wc/wordcount_reducer.py -file /home/linux/wc

Note here I refer to the mapper and reducer scripts with a relative path.

The comment about the file being readable and executable is also correct.

It took me a while to work this out. I hope it helps.